# Why Does/How Can I Stop this From Returning as NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nan

I am working on a website with a Java back end and I am creating graphs with data pulled from a database to the front end as JSONs.

All that works fine, however I am now trying to get the totals of each data point to make an additional line for the graph to represent totals.

My loop below aims to loop through a list named 'series' which contains objects, one field in each object is an array (named data) containing numbers that represent the total figure of sales for that day.

```
var totalsArray = [];
//series is an array of objects
for(var q = 0; q < series.length; q++){
//data is an array found in each of those objects
    for(var w = 0; w < series[q].data.length; w++){

        totalsArray[w] += series[q].data[w];

    }
}
```

However, totalsArray ends up full of NaN. What complicates things is that series.data[] can have varying amounts of values in it.

Just to clarify: I am trying to get the value at x position in each of the objects array, add them up and store them in the x position of totalsArray.

Thanks folks let me know if you need anything further:)

Also I have used console.log() to view series[q].data[w] and they are all numbers.

Comment: Your code never initializes the array elements. They start off `undefined` and adding numbers to `undefined` gives you `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pointy

You're a genius mate sorted me right out:

```
for(var q = 0; q < series.length; q++){

    for(var w = 0; w < series[q].data.length; w++){
        if(totalsArray[w] === undefined){
            totalsArray[w] = 0;
        }

        totalsArray[w] += series[q].data[w];

    }
}
```

edit: @Pointy If you want points then put an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming):

```
//series is an array of objects
//data is an array found in each of those objects
totalsArray = series.map(s => (       
    s.data.reduce((t,d) => (t+=d), 0)
);
```

Use `map` and `reduce` instead of nested `for` loops.

The second argument of the `reduce` method will initialize the total to zero.